# Very simple c++ for statement but it wont cout?

Tags: c++, xcode, for-loop, cout

My question is simple. I have a 'for' statement in a c++ program and when I compile ignores my cout.

I am using xcode, compiling with xcode and here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main () 
    {
      cout << this prints" << endl;
      for(int i=0; i>10; i++)
       {
         cout << "this doesn't" << endl;
       }
     return 0;
    }
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i>10; i++)
```

You initialize `i` to `0` then only enter the body of the loop if `i` is greater than `10`.

The loop loops *as long as the condition `i > 10` is true*, not *until the condition `i > 10` is true.*  This is how all the loops in C++ work:  `for`, `while`, and `do/while`.

Answer (score 4):

Your loop condition is backwards.  You want it to be `i < 10`.

Answer (score 3):

You have got the condition for loop incorrect. This should work. Check below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    cout << "this prints" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<= 10; i++)   // ------> Check the change in condition here
    {
        cout << "this doesn't" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```